# Unity + Android + Websocket: can't connect websocket client

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, networking, websocket

I'm developing a Unity (version 2019.1.11) project where the Android (tested versions 8 and 9) client needs a web socket connection to the server, besides doing some occasional HTTP requests to the server. For that I use [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp). 
For testing purposes I'm running the backend application on my laptop and connect the telephone to its hotspot (web socket address: `ws://192.168.137.1:<port>`), such that no enterprise network is in the way. However, the telephone is unable to connect to the server (tried `port`s tried: 80, 8080, 9000, 11000). The HTTP requests on the other hand work fine. And if I test the application in the editor, it works fine.

Could some please give indications on what I am missing?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark of fiddler on laptop and compare headers in working and non work request from the device(s).

Comment: if you're using a hotspot, it maybe that the device sees 192 as a foreign network and so isnt routing it